# What is represented by $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 x^{n-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to represent the following series in term of a non-infinite function:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 x^{n-1}
$$

Comment: If you start with If $\displaystyle f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n} = \frac{x}{1-x}$ then $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \left(x \frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 x^{n-1}  =  \frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3} $

Answer (score 3):

Yes

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 x^{n}=\frac{(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}
$$

Converges when $|x|<1$

Comment: I think you should divide by $x$ rather than multiply

Comment: @Henry, thanks, I need to get more sleep